# Displaying div tags conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that lists an item, then any reviews it may/may not have. The issue is that there will be an arbitrary (possibly 0) number of reviews. I format each review in its own div element, so I'll have to display 'n' div elements. How can this be done?

Edit, sample element contents:

```
<div id="promo_item">

  Promotion: 

  <br>
  <br>

  <table>

    #rows for item name, price, list-date
    #rows for the values of item name, price, list-date

  </table>

  #comment goes here

</div>
```

This is just an example, I probably won't implement it exactly like this, but I do know there has to be a table for the values.

Comment: This is a very basic Rails question. Every Rails tutorial in the world covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @post.reviews.each do |r| %>
    <div>stuf here <%= r.user.name #etc.... %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to change the properties on the div elements.

You can put this script into your HTML:
[How to Show & Hide your Divs](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/)

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
   }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```